# Extract Quarter -YYYQ1/YYYQ2/YYYQ3/YYYQ4

Tags: oracle

Eg :

```
Select Report_date from ABC
```

Output :

```
2020-12-31
2020-11-30
2020-10-31
2020-09-30
2020-08-31
2020-07-31
2020-06-30
2020-05-31
2020-04-30
2020-03-31
2020-02-29
2020-01-31
```

expectation is If Report date falls on

```
{
2020-03-31
2020-02-29
2020-01-31
}
```

then query should return result of 2020Q1

Comment: If SELECT sysdate, TO_CHAR (sysdate, 'YYYY"Q"Q') AS QTR FROM dual; -->2021-09-17 2021Q3                                                                                   what If i want  output like --> 2021-09-17 2021Q3  2021Q2 ( one less than QTR) as next column ?

Comment: you can use the `ADD_MONTHS` function to subtract 3 months from a date to get the prior quarter using the same `TO_CHAR` function

Comment: Thanks ! tried -SELECT TO_CHAR(
     ADD_MONTHS(sysdate,-5),
     'YYYY"Q"Q') "Next month"
     FROM dual; it works !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `REPORT_DATE` is a `DATE` datatype, you can get the value you are looking for using `TO_CHAR`

```sql
SELECT REPORT_DATE, TO_CHAR (REPORT_DATE, 'YYYY"Q"Q') AS QTR FROM ABC;
```

If `REPORT_DATE` is a `VARCHAR2` datatype, you can get the value you are looking for like this

```sql
SELECT REPORT_DATE, TO_CHAR (TO_DATE(REPORT_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYY"Q"Q') AS QTR FROM ABC;
```

Comment: Thanks @EJ Egyed